# Embeddable React Modal Widget with existing code base where target app is a non React application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-widgets

I am trying to create an embeddable react modal widget that encapsulates login logic already written within the application. The target app may or may not be a react application, given that this widget will be embedded on numerous different applications. Is this possible? Currently I have a React modal widget that opens with the login logic inside, but not in the target application where this will be embedded.

I am using webpack and babel to bundle the appropriate files. Given that this application contains a lot of login logic and is being used in a production env, I've tried to have two separate entries with Webpack (1 for the widget, and 1 for the application code).

For the target app where the widget is going to be embedded, I have tried updating the public/index.html to include the bundled css, and widget js files, but am unable to call any functions in my widget.bundle.js within a script tag.

Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

Widget code in App 1 (LoginModalWidget.js)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./modal.css";
import Modal from "react-modal";
import { FormClose } from "grommet-icons";
import App from "../../App";


const LoginModalWidget = () => {

    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(true);

    function toggleModal() {
        setIsOpen(!isOpen);
    }

    return (
            <Modal
                isOpen={isOpen}
                onRequestClose={toggleModal}
                className="login-modal"
                overlayClassName="modal-overlay"
                closeTimeoutMS={500}
            >
                     <div className="exit-modal-icon">
                    <FormClose size="medium" onClick={toggleModal}/>
                </div>
                <div className="modal-form">
                <App />
                </div>
            </Modal>
    );
}

export default LoginModalWidget;
```

Widget.js to render the widget

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import LoginModalWidget from './components/login-modal-widget/LoginModalWidget';

function renderWidget() {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <LoginModalWidget/>,
    document.getElementById('widget-container')
  );
}

export default {
  renderWidget: renderWidget
};
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development', // or 'production'
  entry: {
    app: './src/index.js',
    widget: './src/widget.js', // your widget's entry file
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'],
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              implementation: require('sass'),
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Target app public index.html

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <title>APPPPPP</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/build/static/css/main.3e38205f.chunk.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>

    <div id="root"></div>
    <div id="widget-container"></div>
    <script src="https://68aad57e.hpe-test.pages.dev/widget.bundle.js" name="widget"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.14.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.14.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

    <script>
      <!--how can I call the renderWidget function from the bundled widget.bundle.js file imported above?---!>
      
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```